# syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'PVOID64' when compiling winnt.h

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

I've recently got the source-code on a application. When im trying to build the solution, I get an error in all parts where `winnt.h` is included. The error codes differs a bit, but they always point to these lines in winnt.h:

```
typedef void *PVOID;
typedef void * POINTER_64 PVOID64;
```

and

```
struct {
    DWORD crc;
    BYTE  rgbReserved[14];
} CRC;
```

So, what could be the cause of this? winnt.h is a standard header and has not been modified. Does it has something to do with me using VS 2010, or me using 64-bit windows? or is it some sort of configuration which is needed?

EDIT:
Here's the exact error-codes:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winnt.h(290): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'PVOID64'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winnt.h(290): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winnt.h(8992): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Buffer'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winnt.h(8992): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winnt.h(8992): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winnt.h(11525): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winnt.h(11525): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winnt.h(11556): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winnt.h(11556): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

Comment: Please post the exact error(s)

Comment: Looks like it's trying to typedef two names at once? Pretty sure that's not standard.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to include `windows.h` rather than `winnt.h`. When you include `windows.h` it will, in turn, include `winnt.h`. You need to do it this way for the necessary macros to be in place that are needed to compile `winnt.h`.

In this case, `POINTER_64` is defined in `BaseTsd.h` like this:

```
#define POINTER_64 __ptr64
```

But if you include `winnt.h` before including `windows.h` then `POINTER_64` is not defined.

Comment: This is happening even when not including winnt.h, related rather with Microsoft's nonsense in DirectX SDK as mentioned in other answer.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using DirectX SDK, try changing the VC++ Directories for include and lib to be searched last.

Comment: thanks, your answer seems to correctly address my issue (compiling a project that targets/includes DirectX 8.1 SDK) without some odd recommendation to remove it (Serov's answer), or (presumably) modify parts of it (as the accepted answer seems to suggest).

Comment: Actually, I had to do the opposite (unless I'm readying you answer improperly).. I had to put the SDK include/Executable/Libraries Directory instances after the standard Include/Executable/Libraries Directory instances: i.e. **ExecutableDirectories:** `$(ExecutablePath);C:\DXSDK\bin`

Comment: What has been pointed out by @BrettCaswell is spot on. If you happen to use property sheets this is what you MUST do to include DirectX directories correctly. Make sure it is **`$(IncludePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Include`** rather than `$(DXSDK_DIR)Include;$(IncludePath)`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your configuration of the Windows SDK is invalid.
This error is caused by the fact that the compiler is unable to recognize the 'POINTER_64' statement.
You may workaround this problem by replacing 'POINTER_64' with '__ptr64'.

I had the same issue recently. Then I've reinstalled the latest version of the Windows SDK and this fixed the problem.

**UPDATE**
@David Heffernan, correctly points to the fact that one should include windows.h instead of winnt.h

Comment: Fantastic, I've this error after a conversion from an old proj.
Both this and Danil Serov answer solves my problem!

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove DirectX SDK if you have one.

Here bug is accepted:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/508204/vc10-0-errors-while-compiling-winnt-h

Comment: Fantastic, I've this error after a conversion from an old proj.
Both this and kids fox answer solves my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Corrected manually syntax in winnt.h :

```
typedef void * POINTER_64 PVOID64; => typedef void * POINTER_64, * PVOID64;
```

Comment: typedef void * POINTER_64;
typedef void * PVOID64;

Comment: You can edit your post if you need to fix something (your comment looks like something that should actually be an update.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using librdkafka, you will get this error whenever "Windows.h" included.

I fixed it by rename "librdkafka/include/basetsd.h" to a different name, or access
this library header via sub path!

I think the author of this library made this file to deal with OS platform compatibility. But with the same file name "basetsd.h" as Windows Core, it just confusing Visual Studio.